# SQL query execution time dramatically increasing

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My problem is explained below.

This is my PHP code running on my server right now :

```
$limit = 10000;
$annee = '2017';

//Counting the lines I need to delete
$sql = " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM historisation.cdr_".$annee." a 
         INNER JOIN transatel.cdr_transatel_v2 b ON a.id_cdr = b.id_cdr ";
$t = $db_transatel->selectAll($sql);

//The number of lines I have to delete
$i = $t[0][0];

do {

    if ($i < $limit) {
        $limit = $i;
    }
    //The problem is comming from that delete
    $selectFromHistoryAndDelete = " DELETE FROM transatel.cdr_transatel_v2
                                    WHERE id_cdr IN (
                                      SELECT a.id_cdr FROM historisation.cdr_".$annee." a
                                      INNER JOIN (SELECT id_cdr FROM historisation.cdr_transatel_v2) b ON a.id_cdr = b.id_cdr
                                    )
                                    LIMIT " . $limit;
    $delete = $db_transatel->exec($selectFromHistoryAndDelete, $params);

    $i = $i - $limit;

} while ($i > 0);
```

[The execution of the query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFZAZ.png)

As you can see on the picture, in the first 195 loops the execution time was between 13 and 17 seconds.
It increased to 73 seconds on the 195th loop and to 1305 seconds on the 196th loop.

Now the query is running for 2000 seconds.

The query is deleting rows in a test table that no one is using right.

I'm deleting row 10,000 by 10,000 for the query to be quick and not overload the server.

I am wondering why is the execution time increasing like that, I though it will be quicker at the end because I though the inner join would be much quicker as they are less rows in the table.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Edit : The tables engine is MyISAM.

Comment: Rollback segments. I think DB keeps somewhere deleted rows to process possible rollback. Try to commit after each delete.

Comment: Sadly I already though about that but my tables are in the tables are in MyIASM, and it does not support the rollback and commit.

Comment: IN is too slow when tables are big. It is much faster to find rows for deleting using JOIN.

Comment: The point is the query was much faster **at the begining** when the table had twice as more rows than now.

Comment: This is because of how storage works with MyISAM. You would need to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` after the deletion to reclaim the free table-space. Effectively there are gaps in the table-space, that are also being processed. Another possible solution is to switch to a PARTITION approach. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41252116/1144627

Comment: Also it seems like `INNER JOIN (SELECT id_cdr FROM historisation.cdr_transatel_test) b ON a.id_cdr = b.id_cdr` is rather redundant since it's not an aggregate query and potentially costly. IIRC the MySQL optimizer might fix this, but if not the entire table would be read. Why not just use `INNER JOIN  historisation.cdr_transatel_test b ON a.id_cdr = b.id_cdr`?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer @fyrye . 
I tried to stop the script to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` but nothing changed sadly.

I had a mistake on the code I copied past above, the `INNER JOIN` is on `cdr_transatel_v2` that's why I have to do it on a select and not just on the table (MySQL doesn't allow to do an `INNER JOIN` and a `DELETE` in the same query on the same table.
I will look the `PARTITION`approach to see if it's possible, but the table is huge.

Comment: After trying few select querys, I found out that @vladatr was rigth : the IN is dramatically slowing the query when I have few rows. I tried to do the query without the IN (instead using INNER JOIN) but I don't think it's possible to do a DELETE across two different database.

Comment: General idea is to JOIN two tables and to have one column that will have values if the IDs are IN, and the other rows will have the NULL value in that column. In that case it is easy to delete all the rows where value IS NOT NULL.

Comment: Another approach would be to use a table to insert the values that should not be deleted (`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`), then use `RENAME TABLE original to backup, temp to original` to replace the original table with the new, and to drop the backup table. This is more beneficial if the deleted values exceed those that are kept or when using InnoDB and the number of records exceed the lock table size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your latest comment the inner join is redundant, since you're deleting from the table that contains the values you're joining on. In essence you're having to process `b.id_cdr = a.id_cdr` twice, since the number of values compared on `cdr_2017` are not changed by the inner join, just the number of values queried to be deleted.

As for the cause of the incremental slowness, it is because you are manually performing the same function as `SELECT cdr_id FROM cdr_2017 LIMIT 10000 OFFSET x`.

That is to say, your query has to perform a full-table scan on `cdr_2017` to determine the id values to delete. As you delete the values, the SQL optimizer has to move further through the `cdr_2017` table to retrieve the values.

Resulting in

```
DELETE FROM IN(1,2,3,...10000)
DELETE FROM IN(1,2,3,...20000)
...
DELETE FROM IN(1,2,3,...1000000)
```

Assuming `cdr_id` is the incremental primary key, to resolve the issue you could use the last index retrieved from `cdr_2017` to filter the selected values.
This will be much faster, as a full-table scan is no longer required to validate the joined records, since you're now utilizing an indexed value on both sides of the query.

```
$sql = " SELECT COUNT(a.cdr_id) FROM historisation.cdr_".$annee." a 
         INNER JOIN transatel.cdr_transatel_v2 b ON a.id_cdr = b.id_cdr ";
$t = $db_transatel->selectAll($sql);

//The number of lines I have to delete
$i = $t[0][0];

//set starting index
$previous = 0;

do {

    if ($i < $limit) {
        $limit = $i;
    }

    $selectFromHistoryAndDelete = 'DELETE d
FROM transatel.cdr_transatel_v2 AS d
JOIN (
   SELECT @previous := cdr_id AS cdr_id
   FROM historisation.cdr_2017 
   WHERE cdr_id > ' . $previous . '
   ORDER BY cdr_id
   LIMIT 10000
) AS a
ON a.cdr_id = d.cdr_id';

    $db_transatel->exec($selectFromHistoryAndDelete, $params);

    //retrieve last id selected in cdr_2017 to use in next iteration
    $v = $db_transatel->selectAll('SELECT @previous'); //prefer fetchColumn
    $previous = $v[0][0];

    $i = $i - $limit;

} while ($i > 0);

//optionally reclaim table-space
$db_transatel->exec('OPTIMIZE TABLE transatel.cdr_transatel_v2', $params);
```

You could also refactor to use `cdr_id > $previous AND cdr_id < $last` to remove the order by limit clauses, which should also improve performance.

Though I would like to note, that a table lock on cdr_transatel_v2 is performed during this operation by the MyISAM database engine. Due to the way MySQL handles concurrent sessions and queries, there is not much gain from a batch delete in this manner, and is really only applicable to InnoDB and transactions. Especially when using PHP with FastCGI, as opposed to Apache mod_php. Since other queries not on cdr_transatel_v2 will still be executed and write operations on cdr_transatel_v2 will still be queued. If using mod_php I would reduce the limit to `1,000` records to reduce queue times.
For more information see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html#internal-table-level-locking

---

Alternative approach.

Considering the large number of records that need to be deleted, when the records deleted exceed those that are kept, it would be more beneficial to invert the operation by using `INSERT` instead of `DELETE`.

```
#ensure the storage table doesn't exist already
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cdr_transatel_temp;

#duplicate the structure of the original table
CREATE TABLE transatel.cdr_transatel_temp 
LIKE transatel.cdr_transatel_v2;

#copy the records that are not to be deleted from the original table
INSERT transatel.cdr_transatel_temp
SELECT * 
FROM transatel.cdr_transatel_v2 AS d
LEFT JOIN historisation.cdr_2017 AS b
ON b.cdr_id = d.cdr_id
WHERE b.cdr_id IS NULL;

#replace the original table with the storage table
RENAME TABLE transatel.cdr_transatel_v2 to transatel.backup, 
    transatel.cdr_transatel_temp to cdr_transatel_v2;

#remove the original table
DROP TABLE transatel.backup;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to think about it and to answer. I will definitly try the first solution today if I can find enougth time for it. @Vladatr talked about the IN performances, so I made my query without it. Now the deletes running in ~0.07 seconds. I will try and see if your query is faster. Thanks again for the help !